# laravel passport password grant Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using 5.5 larevel's version and postman to test the API.

I ran the command

php artisan passport:client --password

To generate id and secret. When I post `localhost:8000/oauth/token`

post:

[image: post]

it returns me a token but when I want to get an enpoints values its returns me  Unauthenticated

[image: Unauthenticated]

here is route api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/users', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/subjects','SubjectController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Apache server, I guess this should help you as it works on mine :

Just add these lines on your .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

as stated in [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-passport-and-postman-gets-all-the-time-unauthorised/replies/332616) thread.

Hope that helps.

Comment: where is the .htaccess file. my project is not running in www/var/

Comment: I added a .htaccess and no function

Comment: The .htaccess file should be inside the public folder. Mine looks like this:`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*) 
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

Check valid access_token.
In my case, Error occur because I just copied a part of access_token.
Ex: 
access_token: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImE2YWU0YjdjNjQzN2NhMjgxNTgxMGZhOGQ1ZmJmNDE5YzUwZDVhMzEyZmRiMzVmYTIyZjA0ZmZmMGQ0MDQxMzU2M2E1YWIyMGM1ODE3ZDAwIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI3IiwianRpIjoiYTZhZTRiN2M2NDM3Y2EyODE1ODEwZmE4ZDVmYmY0MTljNTBkNWEzMTJmZGIzNWZhMjJmMDRmZmYwZDQwNDEzNTYzYTVhYjIwYzU4MTdkMDAiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDczNTEyMjAsIm5iZiI6MTUwNzM1MTIyMCwiZXhwIjoxNTA4NjQ3MjIwLCJzdWIiOiI1OWNkODBlMGQxMzgyMS4zNDYyNDIxNyIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyIqIl19.4aC5jlHlqXYX9_StnwaU_4nSHUlum1gTuNGyKUyDoCs_1s-PYDMRD74gH1sG0l2B2TkGJjM_mHNSNTzQNKxSmHNGCncvQkpQtJQ9-iObJb0gWVHTwBz53GS5FNPcp6VlN5yX8qkZQLvt28uJTAzqdkqtKBt0592Lh7K2TIueRaytQKk_lRc6sud9WdYOojlNK37Og94adbX3nNbtiHKQ2WSsdJTP5IWhsQIRjgYEEhY9phtLdFAuFBK30lDQ3wshlcl4kPo9GBcjfZe0K5I_vISo0v9JzGHkf0xJynhx9SWPtFY4Ol1BwCKztfLiW2oyFLdGY-CKGpJo1iX5AQGmwqWeW6zP3gQ1JTRtpQy6X3HSrTu3TLWamZZWLaB1niIQ7w2jNIhc2NbEW0eUw7xSFuNiWvHneyAPC1FTPKSigL7qtS9_zOi80PHWxQ6yRdRWqiV3HqSYdjzQaLe-RCz4zABiaRP1-YLd0xCUMoGjRSTUOKFkOQSYiTdTYQq2bwHPwjHnmKRiyFRCyiGbTmgnZjQ2nPVSL16x3adg7s5ECk2LlSNrMykB-YVueY6i7M4wF993tmgBGyCtx_mIruFN8-I8vs0cbo2Pv1AFM7Tss1dZ8NMZJRW6mU5M_95AfeNphGpVJ6U4xFZBM6GoXP4yTx-zTBR7xWG404f9yJocqIE`

But i coppied

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImE2YWU0YjdjNjQzN2NhMjgxNTgxMGZhOGQ1ZmJmNDE5YzUwZDVhMzEyZmRiMzVmYTIyZjA0ZmZmMGQ0MDQxMzU2M2E1YWIyMGM1ODE3ZDAwIn0
```