# Lumen Passport Password Grant Returns Unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen, laravel-passport

As the title says, I am unable to authenticate the access token returned by the Password Grant while the Client Credentials Grant works just fine. I've tried the [htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259114/laravel-passport-password-grant-unauthenticated) solution but it didn't work.

In my logs file, it says that I am having an *AuthenticationException* for the Password Grant Token as stated below.

```
#12 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthenticationException(code: 0): Unauthenticated. at /opt/lampp/htdocs/LumenApiGateway/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Middleware/CheckClientCredentials.php:88)
```

From this error, I looked at the class *CheckClientCredentials* and on the said line (88), the condition that causes the *AuthenticationException* is the *$token->client->firstParty()* part. Now I also wonder why is it considered as firstParty token? I hope you could help me. Thanks!

EDIT:

[#1125](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1125) Is opened on github for this issue.

Comment: Try to clear cache `php artisan optimize`

Comment: @EyadJaabo It's not available on Lumen but it has php artisan cache:clear but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I search for an answer for this query, I found out that the recent release of Laravel Passport which is v 8.x, changed the conditions for *CheckClientCredentials* class.

As stated on the merged [PR](https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1040) on Laravel Passport repo itself, that the mentioned class will only accept *client credentials grant*. Which also means that you have to create separate endpoints and apply different middleware for both machine-to-machine authentication and an actual user (password grant) authentication.

There's also a reported [issue](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/898) similar to this query and a suggested [solution](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/898#issuecomment-551023871) to mitigate it which I find acceptable.